# Determine $\textbf{P}(A)$ and $\textbf{P}(\overline{B} | A)$

Tags: probability

Concerning the events $A$ and $B$, the following probabilities are given:  $\textbf{P}(B) = \frac{1}{3}$,  $\textbf{P}(A|B) = \frac{2}{3}$ , $\textbf{P}(A|\overline{B}) = \frac{3}{7}$. Then determine $\textbf{P}(A)$ and $\textbf{P}(\overline{B}|A)$.

Comment: @ajotatxe, yes, sorry I forgot to change the title) But now I did

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Multiplication Principle: $P(A\mid B)P(B) = P(A\cap B)$

Total Probability: $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$

Bayes' Theorem: $P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A)P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$

Comment: Thank you, I got it!